# Redirecting/grep'ing an existing shell's STDOUT

Tags: files, process, gnu-screen, io-redirection, stdout

I run a lot of long running processes (simulations) that print progress to `STDOUT`. I occasionally forget to redirect to `STDOUT` to a file I can `grep`, and it's usually too far along to restart.

**QUESTION:** Without stopping the process, is there a way I can hook into another `STDOUT`?

These are always running in GNU screen with ZSH on OS X 10.7.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a clever [hack](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process) that uses GDB to attach to the process, and a utility named [`dupx`](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/) wraps up this functionality.

From the `dupx` [manpage](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/dupx_man.html):

> Dupx is a simple utility to remap files of an already running program.
>   Shells like Bash allow easy input/output/error redirection at the time
>   the program is started using `>, < -` like syntax, e.g.: `echo 'redirect
>   this text' > /tmp/stdout` will redirect output of `echo` to `/tmp/stdout`.
>
> Standard shells however do not provide the capability of remapping
>   (redirecting) of output (or input, or error) for an already started
>   process. Dupx tries to address this problem by using `dup(2)` system
>   call from inside `gdb(1)`. Dupx is currently implemented as a simple
>   shell wrapper around a `gdb` script.

Comment: Thanks! I had to [make some modifications](https://gist.github.com/2187521), but it does exactly what I need.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it to work.

Comment: [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/) is very neat for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Use screen's `log` command (!)

Since the process is running in a screen session already it's just a matter of telling screen to log the output of that window:

Switch to the script's window, <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> to log.
Now you can :

```
$ tail -f screenlog.2 | grep whatever
```

From screen's man page:

> log [on|off]
>
> Start/stop writing output of the current window to a file "screenlog.n" in  the window's default directory,  where  n  is  the number of the current window. This filename can be changed with the 'logfile' command. If no parameter is given, the state of logging is toggled. The session log is appended to the previous  contents  of  the  file  if  it already exists. The current contents and the contents of the scrollback history are not included in the session log.  Default is 'off'.