# Redirect stderr from an already running script

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout

I've been running a script for several days now. I redirected stdout to `$HOME/mylog`, but didn't redirect stderr since I thought there would be nothing on it. Suddenly thousands of lines started coming out on stderr, so I suspended the job. Is there a way I can redirect stderr to `$HOME/myerr` from now on, without needing to restart the script?

I have sudo access on the box and it's OS X.

Perhaps something using dtools trapping?

I cannot lose the work the script has done so far and restart it from scratch. Is there a way to "dump the in-memory objects" on disk, freeze the program, edit the variables (e.g. the file descriptors) and *resume* with the new context?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting/grep'ing an existing shell's STDOUT](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34806/redirecting-greping-an-existing-shells-stdout)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is possible if you attach the process of the related interpreter to gdb. I tried it with this perl one-liner

```
 perl -e 'do { print "x\n"; sleep(1) } while(1)'
```

and it works but unfortunately not with a similar bash script.

---

First of all you have to figure out the PID of that process whose output you want to capture. Then start `gdb` in another terminal and execute the following gdb-commands

```
attach PID
call close(2)
call open("/abs/olu/te/path/filename", 65, 384)
detach PID
```

after that the whole data that is written to `stderr` is redirected to `/abs/olu/te/path/filename`, since

- `attach PID` attaches the process to gdb and stops it
- `call close(2)` closes the `stderr` filedescriptor of the process (for `stdout` the filedescriptor is 1)
- `call open(...)` opens a new file and takes the lowest unused integer for the newly created filedescriptor and
- `detach PID` continues the process

At least on my machine. The first two lines are POSIX compatible but not the third one.

The second and the third argument of `open` in the third line are documented in `man 2 open`. In my case 65 means that `open` should create the file and open the file write-only i.e. `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT` (defined in `fcntl.h`). The third argument tells open to create the file with read and write permission for the user i.e. `S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR` (defined in `sys/stat.h`). So maybe you have to find out appropriate values on your machine by yourself.

Comment: This worked so stupendously well... hats off!!

Answer (score 8):

This is a crude answer and I hope someone else does better, but if no other ideas surface, attach gdb and force the process to make a few syscalls:

```
(gdb) attach 12345 # target PID
(gdb) p close(2)
(gdb) p open("errfile", O_WRONLY)
(gdb) c
```

Comment: Nifty. I wasn't aware gdb could do that. Is there any way to force it to a specific file descriptor number? Like say if FD 1 is unused, and the `open()` grabs FD 1? Or do you just have to call `dup()` a few times?

Comment: does `p open("errfile", O_WRONLY)` really work on your machine?

Comment: You could stick in a `p dup2(xxx, 2)` and then `p close(xxx)` where `xxx` is the return value of the `open`. This is tricky stuff, better not use these commands on a long-running process until you're sure there's no other choice.

Comment: @user1146332 it did when I tried it because I used `/dev/null` as my `errfile` so I didn't need `O_CREAT`. And `O_WRONLY` being a macro, whether it expands or not depends on whether gdb stopped the process at a line where debugging symbols are available and the macro is defined. Injecting code into a process with gdb is dangerous and nobody just should be copying these commands without understanding them.

Comment: @AlanCurry I don't think that gdb expands macros if general debugging information is available. You have to compile the sources with special flags (see [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_70.html) ). Besides it is very uncommon that an arbitrary executable on your system has debugging information included (let anlone the information are extended with macro information). But i agree with you that code injection is generally not advisable, but there might be cases where you benefit.